# Java: Sort an array using external parameters

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Say I have a function foo, with some parameters. In this function I generate an array m of type Move. I now need to sort this array. Ok, so I break out Arrays.sort(m, Comparator() { ... }. But wait, the function I want to use to compare two moves needs to take the parameters of foo into account, yet a Comparator's compare function can only take two arguments of type Move! See following code for what I want to do.

```
public int compare (Move m1, Move m2, Game g, int id) {
    return g.evaluate(m1, g, id) - g.evaluate(m2, g, id);
}


public int foo (Game g, int id) {
    Move[] m = ... ;

    ???

    // m is now sorted by compare(move1, move2, g, id)
}
```

I do not have access to the Game class itself, so I can't just edit that to solve my problem. The Comparator class seems unable to do this. Is there any way to actually do this in Java?

Comment: You can create a wrapper around game and then sort that using a comparator .

Comment: Make a MoveComparator class that is constructing using a `Game` and an `int`, and stores them as instance variables. The MoveComparator can then compare the two `Move`s it's passed using the `Game` and `int` it already has.

Comment: You could subclass comparator and provide your parameters to it rather that use an anonymous comparator. Then in your implementation which is doing the comparisons you could use those values.

Comment: You can also write your `Comparator` as an anonymous class, and use `g` and `id` directly if you make them **final**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Build your own Comparator :

```
public MyComparator implements Comparator<Move>
{

    private Game game;
    private int id;

    public MyComparator(Game g, int id)
    {
         this.game = g;
         this.id = id;
    }

    // compare function, using game and I'd
 }
```

Use it like that :

```
 Move[] m = ... ;
Arrays.sort(m, new MyComparator(aGame, and));
```